# Echo statement printing the value '1'

Tags: php

When I wanted to test whether the value is properly passed from HTML form to PHP, I found something is wrong with the echo statement.
Here is the HTML text box code

```
<div class = form-group>
                    <label for = 'bcaa'>BCAA 5gms Cost</label>
                    <input type = 'text' class = 'form-control' name = 'bcaa'>
                </div>
```

And here is the PHP code to get the value and print it simply.

```
<?php

$bcaacost = isset($_POST['bcaa']) ;
echo $bcaacost;
?>
```

The value given in the text box is not printed, but simply '1' is printed the more echo statement is added more no of '1' is printed

Like

```
echo "something";
echo "blah blah";
```

The output is

```
11
```

What's the reason for this and what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: The result of an `isset` is a boolean TRUE or FALSE. That should be all you need to know

Comment: `$bcaacost = isset($_POST['bcaa']) ? $_POST['bcaa'] : "";`

Answer (score 2):

Remove `isset()` for variable assigning as it checks veriable `$_POST['bcaa']` is set or not.

```
$bcaacost = $_POST['bcaa'];
```

**Full code**

```
<?php
$bcaacost = $_POST['bcaa'];
echo $bcaacost;
?>
```

[Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) about **isset()**

Answer (score 1):

`isset()` returns `true` or `false` depending on the variable set or not.

```
$bcaacost = isset($_POST['bcaa']) ; // return true / 1
echo $bcaacost; // prints 1
```

it should be like -

```
if(isset($_POST['bcaa'])) {
    echo $_POST['bcaa'];
}
```

Or if you want to print some default, then -

```
$bcaacost = isset($_POST['bcaa']) ? $_POST['bcaa'] : 'Default';
echo $bcaacost;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['bcaa'])) {
    $bcaacost = $_POST['bcaa'] ;    
    echo $bcaacost ;
}
```

Otherwise, `isset($_POST['bcaa'])` will print `1` or `0`

Answer (score 1):

`isset()` checks that a variable exists, and returns either `true`(1) or `false`(0)

To see the contents of `$_POST['bcaa']` you need to check it exists i.e. `isset()` but then use the contents of the variable

```
<?php
$bcaacost = isset($_POST['bcaa']);
if ( $bcaacost ) {
    echo $_POST['bcaa'];
}
?>
```

Or more simply

```
if ( isset($_POST['bcaa']) ) {
    echo $_POST['bcaa'];
}
```

As to your suggestion that :

```
echo "something";
echo "blah blah";
```

will create `11` that cannot be so. Something else must be causing this or you are just confused as to what is creating the `11` output

Answer (score 0):

the result of isset is true or false. In your case the result is true and it assigned back to $bcaacost and that's why it echoing 1.

use following code:

```
<?php

$bcaacost = isset($_POST['bcaa'])?$_POST['bcaa']:"not set";
echo $bcaacost;
?>
```